# How do I build terracotta OSS server version 4.3.5 from source?

Tags: java, terracotta

I need a copy of terracotta open source server 4.3.5.

(Why: I'm updating a legacy app, which I want to get

1. into a docker container
2. updated from Java 7 -> 8
   It's currently running a terracotta client (ehcache-terracotta 2.6.3) that isn't compatible with Java 8 against Terracotta OSS server 3.7.3, and I want to target a later version compatible with the ehcache 2.x API; 4.3.5 already has an official docker build of the server available. Unfortunately, it seems that the Dockerised server can only be used as part of a Docker network, because it identifies its randomised hostname (like `08e76c91d4a6`) as the server host, and the multiplicity of interrelated terrcotta/ehcache dependencies is so brittle I want to get it running locally before trying to add it to a container.)

The official downloads page http://www.terracotta.org/downloads/ refers you to a SVN repo at http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/ with no further instructions.
I've never used SVN, but Googled my way to trying

`svn checkout http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/`

and figured I'd just search for "start-tc-server.sh".
However, this clearly contains multiple projects; I had to stop because the download took hours and filled the available space of my hard disk, and at this point

`find . -name 'start-tc-server'`

returns nothing.

A quick manual inspection of the repo's top level doesn't make it obvious to me what I should be looking for to narrow it down a bit.

I can't find any instructions on the terracotta site, or anywhere else on the internet, on how to turn that link to a monster SVN repository into a running instance of the version of Terracotta server that I want.

How do I do this please?